# how do I tail logs in open shift using oc client

Tags: openshift

From the question you can tell I'm a newb.

At the moment to get the logs of my pod I'm doing a ...

```
oc logs -f api-myapp-v1-48-cdrs2
```

This shows me everything in the log. How can I tail them instead?

Also I was wodering if someone could point me out to a nice cheat sheet of open shift commands? One that is good for beginners.

thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `--tail` option.

```
oc logs api-myapp-v1-48-cdrs2 --tail=50
```

You can use the `--help` option to commands to find out what options they accept.

For some hands on exercises to help you learn OpenShift, see:

- https://learn.openshift.com

Comment: Those interactive tutorials are awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Keep returning to learn.openshift.com. We will continually be adding more exercises over time.

Comment: Is there a way to tail log of all pods of a particular service?

Comment: From the command line only by tailing each pod. If your OpenShift installation has aggregated logging installed, then you can use that from the web console to watch logs across whole application.

Comment: Hmm, I have running one pod of a `my-service`. With `oc logs -f --tail=50 dc/my-service` I have got log of that pod. I will try to spin up multiple pods and see.

Comment: Just tested it with 2 pods running. I have got messages only from the fist created pod. :(.

Comment: Which is what monitoring logs of ``dc`` will do. As I said, you need to run  ``oc logs`` on each pod. There is really no other way from the command line.

Comment: Hmmm :( Can request the feature somewhere ?

Comment: The capability is provided by the aggregated logging feature available through the web console. Have you setup aggregated logging for your cluster?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166750/discussion-between-michal-foksa-and-graham-dumpleton).

Comment: There is nothing else I can tell you. Read the documentation is the best thing you can do to learn about it and steps necessary to set it up. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/install_config/aggregate_logging.html From the web console, if you do have it, click ob 'View Archive' on top right just above log window for a pod.

Answer (score 6):

use `-f` along with `tail`, that will work

```
oc logs -f api-myapp-v1-48-cdrs2 --tail=5
```